# Python Script Doesn't Work After Put It On Crontab

Tags: python

I Have a python file named myfile.py that I want to run it every 1 minute.

When I use this command : 'python myfile.py' It Runs Correctly.

But when I set time for it and put it in crontab it doesn't work.

What the hell is my problem?

my crontab -e configurations:

```
1 * * * * python /home/myuser/Desktop/myfile.py
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot the `/`? `/home...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these codes are correct. Consider this, perhaps your code is in the comment terminal.

You must remove the "#" mark from the beginning of the code.

this is Comment

```
    #1 * * * * python /home/myuser/Desktop/myfile.py
```

this is Correct

```
    1 * * * * python /home/myuser/Desktop/myfile.py
```

Comment: Yes, it was precisely the mistake that I ignored the comment

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a slash before `home`.

Try

```
1 * * * * python /home/myuser/Desktop/myfile.py
```

Comment: Try to be nice, @sepide. Have you looked at your system logs and/or the mail address `cron` is configured to send output to?

Comment: If there are absolutely no log entries about cron (the particular log depends on your system), then it's possible that cron isn't running. Which platform is this on?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly specifying interpreter path?

```
1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/myuser/Desktop/myfile.py
```